# Cleanup in WebWorker when page is closed

Tags: javascript, web-worker, webassembly, onunload

I have a WebAssembly module running in a WebWorker. This module contains a session key for encryption and other sensitive data I want to memzero before the page is closed.

Is there any way to reliably do this for different Browsers?

If not are there any good alternatives? I could intercept onbeforeunload to encourage the user to use the logout button, but as I understand it not all browsers will allow me to send the user a custom message.

Comment: Workers are garbage collected when the page is closed...